# Exchanging limit with integral for functions of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

Assume $F(0, \infty) \times (0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ to be a measurable function such that for every $x>0$
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty } F(x,z) =0. 
$$
I also know that
$$
\int_0^z F(x,z) dx \leq C \quad \forall z >0. 
$$
Can I conclude that
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty } \int_0^z F(x,z) dx  =0 ?
$$

Comment: No? If $F$ is a non-negative function, then the last line implies that $F$ is zero $\lambda(x)$ almost surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is not true. Take the counterexample

$$F(x,z) = \frac{z}{z^2+x^2}$$

The limit goes to $0$ in $z$ and the integral in $x$ is bounded but

$$\int_0^z \frac{z}{z^2+x^2}dx = \arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{4} \not\to 0$$